# ngMockE2E - $http keeps returning <undefined>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, httpbackend, ngmocke2e

I've been trying to write app in Angular 1.6 in ES6 and I wanted to use that fake HTTP Backend from ngMockE2E:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend

So I implemented those API calls like this in home.run.js:

```
mocks.$inject = ['$httpBackend'];

export default function mocks($httpBackend) {

  let users = [{'name': 'Eva'},{'name': 'David'}] 

  $httpBackend.whenGET('/users').respond(users);

  $httpBackend.whenPOST('/users').respond(function(method, url, data) {
    let user = angular.fromJson(data);
    users.push(user);
    return [200, user, {}];
  });

}
```

I also have index.js that looks like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uirouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import mocke2e from 'angular-mocks/ngMockE2E';

import mocks from './home.run'
import routes from './home.config';
import HomeController from './home.controller';

export default angular.module('app.home', [uirouter, mocke2e])
  .config(routes)
  .controller('HomeController', HomeController)
  .run(mocks)
  .name;
```

And HomeController where I call that get method:

```
export default class HomeController {

 constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.users = this.getUsers();
 }

 getUsers() {
   this.$http.get('/users').then(function(response) {
     return response.data;
   });
 }

}

HomeController.$inject = ['$http']
```

Unfortunately getUsers() method in controller keeps returning undefined instead of users from response.data, even after trying different approaches.

Is someone able to figure out where have I messed up?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `return` in `getUsers()`

```
export default class HomeController {

 constructor($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
    this.users = this.getUsers();
 }

 getUsers() {
   return this.$http.get('/users').then(function(response) {
     return response.data;
   });
 }

}
```